# Text-to-speech specific page element?

Tags: web-browser, automation, scraping, speech-synthesis

I'd like to convert [a web page like this](https://www.reddit.com/r/pics/comments/3rm6t3/rare_cloud_phenomenon_over_eastern_victoria/) and have the program filter it for the comments, rather than include "permalink, source" or irrelevant page elements.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. E.g. are you looking for a ready-to-use programm? Then what OS should it run on, what should the output look like? Or are you looking for some library to do it yourself – then what programming language should it be for? In both cases: Any budget you're willing to spend?

Answer (score 0):

A very general question so a very generalised answer:

The following tool chain can, *(on just about any platform)*:

1. Scrape a web page
2. Identify specific elements
3. Read them out loud

   - Programming Language: [Python](http://python.org)
   - Web Scraping: [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) or [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org)
   - Parse Scraped Page: [Beautiful Soup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/) or [Lxml](http://lxml.de/)
   - Text to Speech: Numerous python packages but Google speech might be a good match.

All of the above are Free, *Gratis & Open Source*, and cross platform so will work on at least Windows, Mac OS-X and Linux *your question didn't specify a platform*.

An example for Linux using the command line tools, (curl), and some of the above:

```
curl -s http://api.icndb.com/jokes/random/ | python3 -c 'import html.parser, json, sys; print(html.parser.HTMLParser().unescape(json.load(sys.stdin)["value"]["joke"]))' | google_speech -
```